# strtok returning null at the end

Tags: c, shell, null, strtok

I'm writing a shell that has an "echo" command. For instance, if a user inputs "echo hello world", the shell prints out "hello world".

My code is below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {

  int MAX_INPUT_SIZE = 200;
  char input[MAX_INPUT_SIZE];
  char *command;

  printf("shell> ");
  fgets(input, MAX_INPUT_SIZE, stdin);

  //find first word
  char *space;
  space = strtok(input, " ");
  command = space;

  // printf("command: %s\n",command);

  //echo command
  if (strncmp(command, "echo", MAX_INPUT_SIZE) == 0) {
    while (space != NULL) {

      space = strtok(NULL, " ");
      printf("%s ", space);
    }

    }

  return (EXIT_SUCCESS);

}
```

When I run this, with the input

```
echo hello world
```

the shell prints out

```
hello world
 (null)
```

I'm confused as to why the (null) is printing. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix as below :-

```
if (strncmp(command, "echo", MAX_INPUT_SIZE) == 0) {
   space = strtok(NULL, " "); //eat the "echo"
    while (space != NULL) {
       printf("%s ", space);                         <----+
      space = strtok(NULL, " ");                          |     
//      printf("%s ", space);                        -----+
    }

    }
```

Comment: Will need to do something to avoid printing `echo` initially. Maybe add `space = strtok(NULL, " ");` between the if and the while.

Comment: @POW Thanks, that worked. With this fix, however, there's a space printed on the next line before the command line prompt. Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: @flexcalibur6 If I'm correct, looks like you're on linux terminal.
I can't check that I'm on Windows. What you can probably do is put a `printf("\n");` just before `return` of main. This space is coming due to a trailing space from `printf("%s ", space);`

Comment: @POW That fix is so simple I'm slightly embarrassed I didn't think of it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `space = strtok(NULL, " ");` at the beginning of the while loop.

In my experience, using a while loop has this structure:

```
doA();
while(checkA()) {
  doA();
}
```

Comment: I think you are looking for a `do-while` loop.  A `while` loop should *never* look like this.